# Accelerating towards a photon

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, photons, relative-motion

What will be the relative speed and motion between me and a photon if I would have accelerated towards a photon that is moving away from me?
Would it get away from at a slower velocity relative to me, smaller relative velocity? (by logic) or would it keep moving away from me at the speed of light relative to me (because acceleration is a collection of constant velocity motions  and in each one the velocity of the photon is C relative to me by the special theory of relativity)?

Comment: *"Would i get closer to it (by logic)"* - logic dictates otherwise since the photon is, by stipulation, moving away from you.

Comment: By closer to it I mean that it would get away from in a slower rate relative to me

Comment: Then you should write that in your OP

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the relative velocity of the photon and observer from an external observer’s perspective, the photon always appears to be moving at the same velocity from the moving observer’s frame of reference.

Comment: And what would happen a moment later when by velocity will get bigger? Does the photon would still be with velocity C relative to me after I have accelerated?

Comment: Eh, not really. That only holds strictly if the moving observer is in an inertial frame. If the observer is accelerating, this is not necessarily true.

Comment: My apologies if I was mistaken, I took your question to be measure the relative velocity of light from an accelerated (rather than accelerating) frame of reference (as per Chris’ comment, the velocity of light as seen from an accelerating frame reference is not always constant). My comment only pertains to inertial frames of reference. In answer to your comment: Yes, the velocity of light would appear to be $v=c$, before **and** after the acceleration of the observer, from the frame of reference of the observer.